# Android Firebase Notifications not being shown using custom server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to my android devices using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Apparently everything is OK. I get an answer for my HTTP request:

```
Response Code : 200

{"message_id": **ID here** }
```

But I have an emulator with the APK installed and no notifications are being received, not even when the app is on the foreground.

Everything works fine when messages are sent through the Firebase console.

Anyone can help me to find out what's wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Base64;


    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

            String apiKey = "AI...LoU"; //My key here

            String out = "{\"notification\":{\"title\": \"My title\", \"text\": \"My text\"}, \"to\":\"/topics/all\",\"data\": {\"key\": \"value\"}}";

            URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

            String credentials = "key=" + apiKey;
            //String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes()));

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", credentials);

            conn.connect();

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(out);
            wr.flush();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            wr.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This may be network issue in emulator. After sending notification, in emulator turn on aeroplane mode and turn off aeroplane mode, you will get all notification.

Comment: I receive the notifications when I use the Firebase Console. I think the network is working fine. I just don't receive the notifications when using this http post request.

Comment: Are you positive that device (emulator) is subscribed to the `all` topic?

Comment: Nope! This probably has been my mistake, @AL.
I thought that every device would be subscribed by default to the "all" topic (I have read that somewhere).

Comment: Noted. You just have to subscribe the device to the topic. I'll add in an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do make sure that the device is subscribed to the corresponding topic. In this case, it should be subscribed to `all` by calling [subscribeToTopic()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) on your client side.

Comment: Just complementing! When my app is created, in the onCreate method of the launcher activity, I added the following line:
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");
And now it's working perfectly.